# Corona SDK transition.to and physics body not acting right

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I've got this snippet that seems simple, but doesn't work right. I've got a ball that jumps on screen tap. It does jump on tap, but it seems as if the ball gets heavier with multiple taps and falls down a lot faster. So after about 10 taps it almost falls down off screen instantly. Anyone have any idea why?

```
local function screenTap (event)
  if ball.y > ceiling then
    transition.to(ball, {time=transitionTime,
                         x = ball.x,
                         y = ball.y - jumpHeight,
                         radius = 25})
  end
end

tapArea:addEventListener ("tap", screenTap)
```

Comment: You probably are going to have to post more code before we can know whats going on. How are you creating the ball? Where is the code adding physics to it it?

Answer (score 1):

In physics we don't use transitions. Use force:

```
myBody:applyForce( 500, 2000, myBody.x, myBody.y )
```

Two first two values are for force amount (x, y) and the next two defines single point where force is applied.